# SignalR not invoking server-side method if it has an overload which expects an instance of a class

Tags: vb.net, signalr, overloading

I have this method at `my` Hub:

```
Public Sub SaveFields(ByVal changeSignal As String)
    Dim foo As Integer = 5
End Sub
```

If I call it from client-side like this:

```
testHub.server.saveFields("abc");
```

then `SaveFields` is called successfully. However, if I have a `Class` like this:

```
Public Class WOChangeSignal
    Public WOID As Integer
    Public FieldUpdates As Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

and add an overload for `SaveFields` like this:

```
Public Sub SaveFields(ByVal changeSignal As WOChangeSignal)
    Dim foo As Integer = 5
End Sub

Public Sub SaveFields(ByVal changeSignal As String)
    Dim foo As Integer = 5
End Sub
```

then my call of

```
testHub.server.saveFields("abc");
```

will be unsuccssful, just like my call of

```
testHub.server.saveFields({
    WOID: 1234,
    FieldUpdates: [
        {Key: 2, Value: 4},
        {Key: 3, Value: 5}
    ]
});
```

as none of these tries are actually invoking the server-side method. As a consequence, I assume that the problem is the overload which expects an instance of a `Class`. So, my question is as follows: why is SignalR not invoking none of the overloads if I add an overload expecting `WOChangeSignal` parameter?

Comment: please see this regarding overloading web methods:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921142/net-overload-webmethods-possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921142/net-overload-webmethods-possible)

Comment: See accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686859/signalr-hub-overloads

Comment: @supertopi, I understand that the number of arguments must be different and therefore changes are needed in the code, but I wonder what caused the behavior I described, or to put it simply: what happened under the hood which prevented the system of executing any of the overloads?

Comment: This behavior is *by design*. If the framework doesn't know which overload to execute it's better not to execute any, wouldn't you agree? If you want to see under the hood, go see the source code at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: Implementation at line 135: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/799d9bc32524066344cb3656e5f28f2fd03ba9b3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedMethodDescriptorProvider.cs

Comment: @supertopi, thanks for these comments, they made everything clear. If you convert this to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @LajosArpad It's OK you can accept the answer you wrote up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is the cause:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the specified <paramref name="hub">Hub</paramref> for the specified <paramref name="method"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// In the case that there are multiple overloads of the specified <paramref name="method"/>, the <paramref name="parameters">parameter set</paramref> helps determine exactly which instance of the overload should be resolved. 
    /// If there are multiple overloads found with the same number of matching parameters, none of the methods will be returned because it is not possible to determine which overload of the method was intended to be resolved.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="hub">Hub to search for the specified <paramref name="method"/> on.</param>
    /// <param name="method">The method name to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="descriptor">If successful, the <see cref="MethodDescriptor"/> that was resolved.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The set of parameters that will be used to help locate a specific overload of the specified <paramref name="method"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the method matching the name/parameter set is found on the hub, otherwise false.</returns>
    public bool TryGetMethod(HubDescriptor hub, string method, out MethodDescriptor descriptor, IList<IJsonValue> parameters)
    {
        string hubMethodKey = BuildHubExecutableMethodCacheKey(hub, method, parameters);

        if (!_executableMethods.TryGetValue(hubMethodKey, out descriptor))
        {
            IEnumerable<MethodDescriptor> overloads;

            if (FetchMethodsFor(hub).TryGetValue(method, out overloads))
            {
                var matches = overloads.Where(o => o.Matches(parameters)).ToList();

                // If only one match is found, that is the "executable" version, otherwise none of the methods can be returned because we don't know which one was actually being targeted
                descriptor = matches.Count == 1 ? matches[0] : null;
            }
            else
            {
                descriptor = null;
            }

            // If an executable method was found, cache it for future lookups (NOTE: we don't cache null instances because it could be a surface area for DoS attack by supplying random method names to flood the cache)
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                _executableMethods.TryAdd(hubMethodKey, descriptor);
            }
        }

        return descriptor != null;
    }
```

As we can see, if there is not exactly a single match, then descriptor will be null. It turns out that this is by design and the reason given is as follows:

> If only one match is found, that is the "executable" version,
>   otherwise none of the methods can be returned because we don't know
>   which one was actually being targeted