# ASP.Net Core SignalR hub method overloading

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-5

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686859/signalr-hub-overloads) question, which I presume is before .net core.

I want to do the same thing in a .net 5 project. My hub is like this:

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public async Task TestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public async Task TestMethod(string input) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and in `Startup.cs` when I try `MapHub` I get error

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("test");
});
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Duplicate definitions of 'TestMethod'. Overloading is not supported.'

Is there a breaking change? In which versions of SignalR overloading was supported? How can I get around this porblem?

PS. The original case is that I have an existing hub that I want to change some method signatures without breaking change.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot overload. It is the same with Methods in Controllers. If you have two get methods with the same name what should the get request bind to. Keep in mind that the routing module first finds the correct method to invoke before deserializing the body. That being said you could have a redirect to the old method in the new method so that you do not break anything.

Comment: But there must be some way. Maybe I can override the hub locator functionality in the framework?